# The designated data directory MySQL is unusable

Tags: mysql, innodb, bitnami, mysql-innodb-cluster

I use bitnami/mysql to use mysql in k8s.
I used this command:

```
helm install my-sql bitnami/mysql --set global.storageClass=rook-cephfs --set image.debug=true --set auth.rootPassword="SAra131064" --set auth.username=ali --set auth.password=ali1234 --set volumePermissions.enabled=true
```

but I got error :

```
The designated data directory /bitnami/mysql/data/ is unusable
```

After that I use diagnosticMode and execute this command (`/opt/bitnami/scripts/mysql/entrypoint.sh /opt/bitnami/scripts/mysql/run.sh`) in pod and get that error again.
before this command there isn't any file in /bitnami/mysql and

```
total 0
drwxrwxrwx 2 1001 1001  0 Dec 15 14:15 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 19 May 11  2022 ..
```

After execute that command :

```
total 0
drwxrwxrwx 3 1001 1001  1 Dec 15 14:18 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 19 May 11  2022 ..
drwxr-xr-x 2 1001 root  1 Dec 15 14:18 data
```

and there is auto.cnf in data directory.

What is the problem? What should I do?
Please help me

```
2022-12-15T14:21:00.199807Z 1 [Warning] [MY-012582] [InnoDB] io_setup() failed with EAGAIN. Will make 5 attempts before giving up.
2022-12-15T14:21:00.199888Z 1 [Warning] [MY-012583] [InnoDB] io_setup() attempt 1.
2022-12-15T14:21:00.700312Z 1 [Warning] [MY-012583] [InnoDB] io_setup() attempt 2.
2022-12-15T14:21:01.200805Z 1 [Warning] [MY-012583] [InnoDB] io_setup() attempt 3.
2022-12-15T14:21:01.701219Z 1 [Warning] [MY-012583] [InnoDB] io_setup() attempt 4.
2022-12-15T14:21:02.201614Z 1 [Warning] [MY-012583] [InnoDB] io_setup() attempt 5.
2022-12-15T14:21:02.702315Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012584] [InnoDB] io_setup() failed with EAGAIN after 5 attempts.
2022-12-15T14:21:02.702619Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012954] [InnoDB] Cannot initialize AIO sub-system
2022-12-15T14:21:02.702731Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012929] [InnoDB] InnoDB Database creation was aborted with error Generic error. You may need to delete the ibdata1 file before trying to start up again.
2022-12-15T14:21:02.703266Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010020] [Server] Data Dictionary initialization failed.
2022-12-15T14:21:02.703342Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-013236] [Server] The designated data directory /bitnami/mysql/data/ is unusable. You can remove all files that the server added to it.
2022-12-15T14:21:02.703591Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2022-12-15T14:21:02.704631Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /opt/bitnami/mysql/bin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.29)
```

Comment: Is `mysql` the user and group `1001`?

Comment: @RickJames yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disabling the [innodb_use_native_aio](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_use_native_aio) as your storage doesn't support it.

Add this to your [my_custom.cnf](https://github.com/bitnami/containers/tree/main/bitnami/mysql#configuration-file) file like:

```
[mysqld]
innodb_use_native_aio=0
```

Comment: This config doesn't have any side effect?

Comment: no. There's a fully compatible non-native async IO implementation.